# Where to find the Azure AD Auth Failure logs?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have problem authenticating with Azure AD occasionally. I get the error that shown at the bottom of the page.

I set the following

`IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;`

to see the logs to find out what configuration that I'm missing. Where can I see the logs?

I'm running the **WebAPI** locally on my machine and the URL is `https://localhost:16135/weatherforecast`. I get the token via **POSTMAN** which is succeeding but using that token to execute the *WebAPI* is failing with the error.
This is the error that I see:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
```

Comment: have you tried this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins

Comment: The activity report says the login is successful. I get the right token from **Azure AD** to **POSTMAN**. The failure is happening when accessing the **WebAPI**.

Comment: How is authority configured in your startup.cs? With https?

Answer (score 1):

The error says "No such host in known"

If you are making a call to the WebAPI from outside your local machine. Then it will not find localhost.

Try using the name of your machine in the uri.

Comment: I'm running **POSTMAN** app locally. I get the token from **AzureAD** in **POSTMAN** which is succeeded. Then I pass the token in **POSTMAN** to make a call to the **WebAPI**. All are running locally on my box.

Comment: The error stopped happening after I cleared the authorization in **POSTMAN** and reentered the details. I will keep this question open for the solution of where the logs can be seen.